# Не работает конструкция if в if в python с библиотекой telebot

Tags: python, telebot, if

```
import contextlib
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def gg(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот '+ 'что-то' +"еще что-то")
    elif message.text == 'группа':
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "чет или нечет")
          if message.text == 'чет':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нечет')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

не работает if в if . бот не отправляет сообщение "нечет" во втором if  elif, все условия соблюдены. в простых кодах с цифрами конструкция работает, но с библиотекой - нет. очень много всего попробовал, ниче не помогает. токен убрал из кода по объективным причинам. заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас не совсем верна логика алгоритма. То есть:

1. Приходит сообщение, например, *`группа`*
2. Процесс переходит в конструкцию `elif`
3. Отправляется сообщение *`чёт или нечет`*
4. А вот далее, вы получаете сообщение, например, *`чёт`*, **но вы обрабатываете опять же конструкцию начальную**, то есть:

```
if message.text == '/start':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот '+ 'что-то' +"еще что-то")
    elif message.text == 'группа':
```

Следовательно, у вас ничего не происходит.

Вам нужно добавить ещё одну функцию, которая будет обрабатывать дальнейшие сообщения, либо все условия установить на одном уровне, то есть, к примеру:

```
if message.text == '/start':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот '+ 'что-то' +"еще что-то")
elif message.text == 'группа':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "чет или нечет")
elif message.text == 'чет':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нечет')
```

Но, лучше добавить ещё один обработчик. То есть, написать, например, так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def gg(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я бот '+ 'что-то' +"еще что-то")
    elif message.text == 'группа':
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "чет или нечет")
          bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chet_or_nechet)

def chet_or_nechet(message):
    if message.text == 'чет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нечет')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: нет ,не совсем мне нужно, чтобы бот спрашивал "чет или нечет" только, если до этого пользователь отправил сообщение "группа"

Comment: @генадий тогда, как я написал выше, используйте дополнительную функцию.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, показать куда именно и как ее впихнуть?) я просто уже пытался

Comment: @генадий хорошо, я сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: спасибо большое. сейчас попробую

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛШОЕ. РАБОТАЕТ!!!!!

Comment: @генадий не за что) если вам ответ помог, пожалуйста, оцените его)

Comment: попробовал сунуть так же еще одну функцию. не работает.(

Comment: @генадий смотрите, в новой функции вы также пишите `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, имя функции, которая дальше обрабатывает сообщение)` и опять создаёте функцию, теперь с новым именем. Я бы посоветовал вам разобрать пример из данной статьи, а также проанализировать содержимое статьи: https://habr.com/ru/post/442800/